# Installing Agensgraph version of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to install Agensgraph on postgresql

I have changed the configure file to use port 5435

I follow the INSTALL file instructions, at the following line I get an error

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &  
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb test

createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to 
server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here's the full routine

```
./configure
make
su
make install
adduser postgres
mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/data
chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
su - postgres
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &  
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb test
```

log file contents

```
2018-05-22 07:54:49.873 CEST [13186] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address already in use
2018-05-22 07:54:49.873 CEST [13186] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2018-05-22 07:54:49.873 CEST [13186] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
2018-05-22 07:54:49.873 CEST [13186] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2018-05-22 07:54:49.873 CEST [13186] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2018-05-22 07:54:49.873 CEST [13186] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I have another instance of postgresql running on default port 5432, so it looks like the Agens version of postgresql is trying to use the default port, even though I specified 5435 in the configure file. Any ideas?

```
grep -H '^port' /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf:port = 5432
```

Comment: So why didn't you change `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: I have one postgresql instance on port 5432 as set in postgresql.conf, during the Agensgraph install it installs to the /usr/local/ directory and says it has installed postgresql, I've changed the port in the /usr/local/ version, and restarted postrges, but the error remains.